# Update Flash Builder mobile app to use 64 bit with Air SDK 18.0

Tags: apache-flex, ios8, air, 64-bit, flash-builder

I am having a terrible time updating my Flex Project to use 64bit and iOS 8.  I have to update because when I use Adobe Air SDK 14 I get the following error while uploading my release version via the Application Loader.

[image]

I've followed all of the instructions listed in the following, but nothing works:

http://easynativeextensions.com/making-your-ios-apps-universal/

https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-builder/kb/overlay-air-sdk-flash-builder.html

https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/how-overlay-air-sdk-flex-sdk.html

When I change the line in my air descriptor mxl file to:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/18.0">
```

I get the following error:

[image]

I've downloaded the Air SDK from this page: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html

I tried using both the main link and the Flex specific SDK only link.

[image]

Then I installed the Air SDK in /Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/eclipse/plugins/com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722

[image]

Also, I used the Apache Flex SDK installer to get the latest flex SDK to be used with Air SDK 18.

[image]

It seems to have installed fine

[image]

As you can see I've tried multiple versions.  I also select the air version in my Flex Project compiler path.

[image]

I even tried overlaying the SDK in the Flash Builder SDKs folder.

[image]

Still, I always get the error when I try to set my app descriptor XML line to 18.0

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/18.0">
```

I can set it to 16.0 and the application will build.

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/16.0">
```

But then when I build, my app has a ton of UI problems.  Spinners go crazy and tab bars, buttons, and layout all have problems.  My app goes from looking like this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

I have no idea what to do.

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you find an answer?

Comment: I have the same problem as well, did anyone find a solution?

Comment: Any solution out there??

Answer (score 0):

Menu -> Clean Project ....

Next, rebuilding